# Table viewer and editor cannot be used

Tags: rubymine

I installed the latest version(2016.1) of Rubymine and found the icon of table editor is disabled. I used to click this icon or double click the database name to see the tables and the structure.

[image]

It works well in my last version, but something goes wrong now. I notice there is always a loading symbol. Maybe this is the problem that tables aren't be loaded? By the way the connection to the database is all right, I can execute SQL query.

And here is what it should be(from official website). Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not in the context of an actual *table* when you click on the database icon there.  Notice how you can also elect to duplicate the database, whereas if you're editing a table, you actually *can't* duplicate that.

After your tables load, you should be able to use the tool to edit them again.

Answer (score 0):

Select database, after that click button `Synchronize`, after that you will be able to edit tables via UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add the database to the UI using "Import from sources" option.

Comment: This is not an answer. This could be a simple comment.

Comment: Depends upon what your definition of answer is. <- this is a simple comment.